# How to mock a function within another function that is imported from a module using typescript and jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking

Here is the function I want to test inside **action** directory:

```
import { Action, ActionProgress, ActionStatus, MagicLinkProgress } from '../../interfaces'
import { areSameActions } from '../actionsProgress'

export const findActionProgressToDisplay = (progress: MagicLinkProgress, actions: Array<Action>): ActionProgress => {
  const actionProgressFound = progress.actionsProgress.find(
    (actionProgress) => actionProgress.status === ActionStatus.PENDING && actions.some((action) => areSameActions(actionProgress.action, action))
  )
  if (!actionProgressFound) {
    throw new Error('No action found to display')
  }

  return actionProgressFound
}
```

The function findActionProgressToDisplay called another function named areSameActions which is imported from ../actionsProgress.

Here is the function that I want to mock :

```
import { Action } from '../../interfaces'

export const areSameActions = (firstAction: Action, secondAction: Action): boolean =>
  firstAction.origin === secondAction.origin && firstAction.type === secondAction.type && firstAction.url === secondAction.url
```

And now the test I tried with jest:

```
import { mockActions } from './../../mocks/campaigns/index'
import { mockActionsProgress, mockProgress } from './../../mocks/magicLinks/index'
import { findActionProgressToDisplay } from './index'
import { describe, test, expect } from '@jest/globals'
import { ActionStatus } from '../../interfaces'
import * as module from '../actionsProgress/index'

module.areSameActions = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)

describe('=== findActionProgressToDisplay ===', () => {
  test('should return true', () => {
    const progress = mockProgress({ actionsProgress: mockActionsProgress() })
    const actions = mockActions()
    const actionFound = findActionProgressToDisplay(progress, actions)

    expect(actionFound.status).toEqual(ActionStatus.PENDING)
  })
})
```

But I get the following error: Cannot assign to 'areSameActions' because it is a read-only property
Which is OK I think because areSameActions is a const.

I also tried :

```
import { mockActions } from './../../mocks/campaigns/index'
import { mockActionsProgress, mockProgress } from './../../mocks/magicLinks/index'
import { findActionProgressToDisplay } from './index'
import { describe, test, expect } from '@jest/globals'
import { ActionStatus } from '../../interfaces'
import * as module from '../actionsProgress/index'

jest.spyOn(module, 'areSameActions').mockReturnValue(true)

describe('=== findActionProgressToDisplay ===', () => {
  test('should return true', () => {
    const progress = mockProgress({ actionsProgress: mockActionsProgress() })
    const actions = mockActions()
    const actionFound = findActionProgressToDisplay(progress, actions)

    expect(actionFound.status).toEqual(ActionStatus.PENDING)
  })
})
```

But I get the error: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: areSameActions
at Function.defineProperty ()
I don't really understand why.

Finally I tried:

```
import { mockActions } from './../../mocks/campaigns/index'
import { mockActionsProgress, mockProgress } from './../../mocks/magicLinks/index'
import { findActionProgressToDisplay } from './index'
import { describe, test, expect } from '@jest/globals'
import { ActionStatus } from '../../interfaces'
import { areSameActions } from '../actionsProgress/index'

jest.mock('../actionsProgress/index', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../actionsProgress/index') // Step 2.
  return {
    ...original,
    areSameActions: jest.fn(),
  }
})
describe('=== findActionProgressToDisplay ===', () => {
  test('should return true', () => {
    areSameActions.mockImplementation(() => (true))

    const progress = mockProgress({ actionsProgress: mockActionsProgress() })
    const actions = mockActions()
    const actionFound = findActionProgressToDisplay(progress, actions)

    expect(actionFound.status).toEqual(ActionStatus.PENDING)
  })
})
```

But I get the error: Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '(firstAction: Action, secondAction: Action) => boolean'
Which I think is OK because in the current context, areSameActions is a function, not a mock.

How to mock / stub / spy the function areSameActions in order to test findActionProgressToDisplay ?

Answer (score 0):

The last tried was near to the truth.

Indeed, jest.mock mock a module when it is required.
So:

```
jest.mock('../actionsProgress/index', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../actionsProgress/index') // Step 2.
  return {
    ...original,
    areSameActions: jest.fn(),
  }
})
```

Create the mock successfully.
But for a reason I don't understand, typescript think that areSameActions is a function instead of a mock. So I help it a bit by telling it to consider my function to be a Mock.

Here is the solution:

```
import { mockActions } from './../../mocks/campaigns/index'
import { mockActionsProgress, mockProgress } from './../../mocks/magicLinks/index'
import { findActionProgressToDisplay } from './index'
import { describe, test, expect } from '@jest/globals'
import { ActionStatus } from '../../interfaces'
import * as module from '../actionsProgress/index'

jest.mock('../actionsProgress/index', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../actionsProgress/index')
  return {
    ...original,
    areSameActions: jest.fn(),
  }
})

describe('=== findActionProgressToDisplay ===', () => {
  test('should return the founded action', () => {
    module.areSameActions as jest.Mock
    // @ts-ignore
    module.areSameActions.mockImplementation(() => true)
    const progress = mockProgress({ actionsProgress: mockActionsProgress() })
    const actions = mockActions()
    const actionFound = findActionProgressToDisplay(progress, actions)

    expect(actionFound.status).toEqual(ActionStatus.PENDING)
  })

  test('should throw error because this case is not supposed to happen', () => {
    module.areSameActions as jest.Mock
    // @ts-ignore
    module.areSameActions.mockImplementation(() => false)
    const progress = mockProgress({ actionsProgress: mockActionsProgress() })
    const actions = mockActions()
    expect(() => findActionProgressToDisplay(progress, actions)).toThrowError('No action found to display')
  })
})
```